# jstree icon not aligned with element text

Tags: css, alignment, jstree

I am using margin-top in CSS on the jstree as follows:

```
.jstree li a {
color:rgb(80,80,80);
font-size:130%;
vertical-align:middle;
margin-top:10px;
}
```

However, the jstree expansion icon (right-pointing arrow) is aligned higher than the element as shown here: [from another question here](http://www.nicholaschase.com/jstree/test.html)

How do I get the icon to align with the element text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this styling,

```
.jstree-default .jstree-no-dots .jstree-closed > ins {
  background-position:0 4px;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome, moreover you can try same using firebug in firefox.